# Is it possible to set the select list dynamically in MSSQL server2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I have a requirement to populate the select list dynamically, Could you please suggest any solution?

Example:

```
DECLARE @DATE CHAR
SET @DATE='E.TERMINATION_DATE'
--SET @DATE='E.HIRE_DATE'
SELECT E.ID,E.FIRSTNAME,E.LASTNAME, @DATE FROM DBO.EMPLOYEES E
```

Is it possible to set the column name in select query?
For some query i need to set the variable `@DATE as TERMINATION DATE` and for some query i need to `set @DATE as E.HIREDATE.`
When i will run the query based on the TERMINATION_DATE then i will comment in the other option.
or do you have any other workaround?

Comment: You need to use the `Dynamic sql query`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Dynamic sql. But you should read [this blog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to know about it.

```
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(100),
  @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

IF YOURCONDITION
  BEGIN
   SET @DATE='E.TERMINATION_DATE'
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
   SET @DATE='E.HIRE_DATE'
  END

SET @SQL = 'SELECT E.ID,E.FIRSTNAME,E.LASTNAME,' + @DATE +' FROM DBO.EMPLOYEES E'
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: 1. `+` are missing
2. DECLARE @DATE CHAR is defaul of size 1

Comment: Also,  exec sp_executesql @SQL

Comment: Sorry, but one more :) delete brackets here, its a stored proc.
exec sp_executesql @SQL

Answer (score 0):

you can use variables in select query but you should assign that query to some variable and execute that variable

because in SSMS at first it will checks(run time) then it executes. In our scenario the variable is assigning at execution only

so we need to assign it to variable as @coderofcode told

```
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(100),
        @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @DATE='E.TERMINATION_DATE'
 SET @SQL = 'SELECT E.ID,E.FIRSTNAME,E.LASTNAME,' + @DATE +' FROM    DBO.EMPLOYEES E'
 exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was writing a function for which i need to use execution_date for some case and for some other case i need to use hire_date.
So i think i can now populate this things dynamically and it's a great invention for me. Thanks all specially Giorgi, coder of code and koushik.
I am using this pseudo code here.

--Setting the condition parameters
    DECLARE @HIRE_DATE DATETIME,
    SET @HIRE_DATE= SELECT MIN(HIRE_DATE) FROM E.EMPLOYEES WHERE          E.PERSON_ID>30000
--based on condition setting the variable dynamically.
     IF @HIRE_DATE IS NULL
    BEGIN
      SET @DATE='E.TERMINATION_DATE'
    END
     ELSE
     BEGIN
       SET @DATE='E.HIRE_DATE'
     END

--setting the sql to execute.
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(E.NR) AS    ACTIVITIES,E.CLI_FIRSTNAME,E.CLI_LASTNAME,E.DEBTORNR,' + @DATE +' FROM        DBO.EMPLOYEES E
      GROUP BY E.CLI_FIRSTNAME,E.CLI_LASTNAME,E.DEBTORNR,' + @DATE
      exec(@sql)